# Rails routing constraints with a nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Let me briefly explain how I'd like the routes to work, and then show you the code I'm working with. I'd like the following to happen:

```
hearing-providers/any-text-but-a-state-abbreviation -> dispensers controller

hearing-providers/TX -> regions#show

hearing-providers/TX/dallas -> cities#show
```

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
  resources "hearing-providers", controller: 'dispensers', as: 'dispensers'  do 
    constraints( region_id: /A[KLRZ]|C[AOT]|D[CE]|FL|GA|HI|I[ADLN]|K[SY]|LA|M[ADEINOST]|N[CDEHJMVY]|O[HKR]|P[AR]|RI|S[CD]|T[NX]|UT|V[AIT]|W[AIVY]/ ) do
      collection do
        get ':state_abbreviation' => 'regions#show', :as => :region
        get ':state_abbreviation/:city_name' => 'cities#show', :as => :city
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem is this:

**It doesn't matter what the path is, I'm always getting routed to the regions controller. The constraints setup doesn't seem to be working.**

Comment: Have you tired using `state_abbreviation` within your constraint instead of `region_id`?

Comment: Ah, yes that works, THANKS! Want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined a constraint for `region_id`, but you are not using it within your routes. Change your constraint to:

```
constraints( state_abbreviation: /A[KLRZ]|C[AOT]|D[CE]|FL|GA|HI|I[ADLN]|K[SY]|LA|M[ADEINOST]|N[CDEHJMVY]|O[HKR]|P[AR]|RI|S[CD]|T[NX]|UT|V[AIT]|W[AIVY]/ ) do
```

and all should work.

Comment: Thanks again. Silly mistake, but your answer helped!